# C# How can I read an MDB database into memory and query it?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to be able to copy a database into a byte array and then query it. Is this possible?

For example, with a text file I can use..

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes;
```

..and then read the byte array with..

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(file));
```

Comment: Any reason a DataSet isn't good enough?

Comment: MDB... which exact engine would that be? And no, you can't. You have to use the functions for that engine to load and query it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In order to query it, the database classes will require the database to reside on disk.  MDB files, in particular, require a lock file to be generated when you open the database.